# How to get the link tag inside a div and append the onclick statement with 'return false' in javascript only

Tags: javascript

I forgot to add

```
return false;
```

to an onclick event on 78+pages and I don't want to edit 78 pages. I need to add it because Chrome moves the screen up and down when the link is clicked and its important that it doesn't. I haven't given the link that contains the onclick an id so I need to grab it, the only link, inside that div and amend it so it says

```
onclick="myFunction(); return false;"
```

NOT

```
onclick="myFunction();"
```

I have tried many things inc.

```
document.getElementById('shuffle-the-deck').getElementsByTagName('a').setAttribute( 'onClick', 'javascript: startShuffle(); return false;' );
```

I have to upload each change to test it and it's driving me nuts!

I would be grateful for help,

Comment: Just use a search and replace tool... ???

Comment: Like I said in the Question. I don't want to edit the link that is repeated on 78 pages :)

Comment: wouldn't you have to add the javascript edit to all 78 pages?

Comment: No I trying to amend the tag with javascript after page load. The link with onclick event is already there, it just needs 'return false' popped on the end :)

Comment: could jQuery .replaceWith() help you to dynamically rewrite the element in question? Although, personally, I'd go with the edit. Notepad++, for example, can search and replace in all 78 files in a jiffy

Comment: @groovy really? it opens individuals files, finds and replaces certain words for you? WOW, I hope so. I will check that out

Comment: sure, just press CTRL+F and look at the "Find in Files" tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work for the first anchor (use a loop if you have more):

```
var anchor = document.getElementById('shuffle-the-deck').getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
anchor.onclick = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // prevents the browser from following the href
                        // just like "return false"
    startShuffle();
}
```

On IE8 and older you have to set the `returnValue` property of the event object. So a more cross-browser approack would be:

```
var anchor = document.getElementById('shuffle-the-deck').getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
anchor.onclick = function(e) {
    (e.preventDefault) ? e.preventDefault() : e.returnValue = false; 
    startShuffle();
}
```

Comment: this is not cross browser at all

Comment: @d4rkpr1nc3 Fair enough, answer updated. Not sure if this is what the OP is looking for, though.

Comment: @bfavaretto Thank you, THANK YOU! Thank goodness Your answer was perfect. I will accept your answer in a mo, it won't let me right now!

Comment: @d4rkpr1nc3 the jumping/screen scrolling problem is only on Chrome.